# Postgres on Heroku - Intermittent Errors

Tags: heroku

After migrating an existing Rails 3 app to Heroku, I am getting a lot of intermittent Postgres errors reported to Airbrake. In particular, a bunch of these errors occur every few hours: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR: out of memory DETAIL: Failed on request of size 1375.`

The origin of the error is usually a basic SELECT statement to retrieve data for the home page of the app (nothing too heavy), e.g.`SELECT "warnings".* FROM "warnings" WHERE (latitude::numeric != 0) ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 100`

Does anyone know what could be causing these errors? I currently use 1 Web Dyno and 1 Worker Dyno (for running a background job every 2 mins) and on the Postgres Dev Plan (less than 10,000 rows).

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like your heroku instance is running on a very limited memory VM or something.  How much memory does it have allocated to it?

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply. It turned out to be an intermittent issue that resolved itself after a couple of days.

Comment: @Tim How many days did it take? I'm receiving the same alert.

Comment: Looks like a problem with Heroku platform (see comments)

Comment: you should contact the heroku support. usually they upgrade you to a less busy instance.